# Cyclic Groups - $a^k = e \text{ iff } n|k$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, cyclic-groups

I saw this proof in the book on Abstract Algebra. Here is part of it:

Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $n$ and $a$ is the generator of $G$. Then $a^k = e \iff n|k$

Proof: Suppose $a^k=e$. By the division algorithm, $\exists q,r \text{ such that } k=nq+r$ where $0\le r < n$. So $e=a^k = a^{nq+r} = a^{nq}a^r = ea^r = a^r$

My question is: is this circular, because we are already assuming that $a^{nq} = e$?

Comment: In any group $G$ of order $n$ you have $a^n=e$ (which follows from Lagrange's theorem) for any element $a\in G$, but in a cyclic group where $a$ is the generator, this equation follows almost trivially.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Did you mean cyclic group $G$?

Comment: This also holds in an arbitrary group. For a cyclic group, the proof is a bit shorter, though.

Comment: @StefanHamcke do you have a proof for an arbitrary group?

Comment: The proof uses cosets. Given a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$, the sets $aH=\{ah\mid h\in H\}$, for $a\in G$, partition $G$, and the function $H\to aH, h\mapsto ah,$ is a bijection, so all cosets have the same size. That means in a finite group $G$, we have $|G|=k|H|$, where $k$ is the number of cosets. As a consequence every subgroup's order is a divisor of the group's order. This also holds for cyclic subgroups, so every element's order divides the group order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exponent laws still work in groups, so we can prove that $a^{nq}=e$ by noting:
$$a^{nq}=\left(a^n\right)^q=e^q=e$$
where the first two expressions both expand to $$\underbrace{a\cdot a\cdot a\cdot \ldots\cdot  a \cdot a}_{nq\text{ times}}$$
and the next follows from replacement with $a^n=e$.

Moreover, notice that the statement $a^{nq}=e$ is exactly the same as

> $n|k$ implies $a^k=e$

whereas the proof you present aims to show the converse:

> $a^k=e$ implies $n|k$

So it's not actually circular - the premise it is taking is distinct from what it is proving and can be proven separately.

Comment: Why are we allowed to assume $a^n = e$?

Comment: @SalmonKiller One way is to note that *every* element of a group of order $n$ has $a^n=e$ (from Lagrange's theorem). More specifically though, since $a$ generates the group, you can write $G=\{e,a,a^2,a^3,\ldots\}$ and since this set must have $n$ elements, we can conclude that the elements $\{e,a,a^2,\ldots,a^{n-2},a^{n-1}\}$ are distinct (and are all of $G$) which tells us both that $a^n$ must cycle back to $e$ and that $a^r$ can't be $e$ for $0<r<n$.

Comment: Ah got it. I missed the division algorithm beauty there. :)